# .Net Core how to show display name instead of Email address?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, smtp, displayname-attribute

I've built an email service using SMTP (System.net.mail nuget package) which also sends out text messages. When I send an email it shows the display name using the following technic:

```
MailAddress from = new MailAddress("fromEmailId@gmail.com", "DisplayName");
```

But while sending text messages it doesn't work. It shows the entire email address instead of the display name.
Attached is the snapshot for reference. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vBKQy.png)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.please provide some code for understanding. and also read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Add code part of your text sending message.